# Lua for loop help!

Tags: lua

I have the following code

```
tile_width = 64;
tile_height = 64;

tile_map = {
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1}
}

i=1;
j=1;
while i<table.getn(tile_map) do
    while j<table.getn(tile_map[i]) do
        print(tile_map[i][j]);
        x = (j * tile_width / 2) + (i * tile_width / 2)
        y = (i * tile_height / 2) - (j * tile_height / 2)
        print(x);
        print(y);
        j = j+1;
    end
i = i+1;
end
```

And it works, but it only displays the first row values, and doesn't go onto the second row, third row, etc.

What I am trying to do in another language

```
for (i = 0; i < tile_map.size; i++):
    for (j = 0; j < tile_map[i].size j++):
        draw(
            tile_map[i][j],
            x = (j * tile_width / 2) + (i * tile_width / 2)
            y = (i * tile_height / 2) - (j * tile_height / 2)
        )
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: If it is Lua 5.1, do not use `table.getn` unless you're absolutely sure that it is what you need. Use `#`.

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by use #?

Comment: Why are you using `while` instead of `for`?

Comment: That is table length operator. http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset j to 1 after each of the inner loops. Because: After the inner loop has been completed for the first time, j will have been incremented 64 times. But you want to start over with j set to 1.

In the code of the other programming language, note that this re-setting of j is taken care of.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a cleaned up version of your code.

Note changes:

1. Use `local` variables instead of global.
2. Use `#` for table size instead of `table.getn()`.
3. Use numeric `for` loop instead of `while`.
4. Lack of semicolons.

If you'll uncomment `io.write()` calls and comment out `print`s, you will get your map printed out in a readable way.

```
local tile_width = 64
local tile_height = 64

local tile_map = {
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1}
}

for i = 1, #tile_map do
  local row = tile_map[i]
  for j = 1, #row do
    --io.write(row[j])
    print(row[j])
    local x = (j * tile_width / 2) + (i * tile_width / 2)
    local y = (i * tile_height / 2) - (j * tile_height / 2)
    print(x)
    print(y)
  end
  --io.write("\n")
end
```

P.S. Make sure you've read the [Programming in Lua 2nd Edition](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/pil2/) book. Note that the version, available online, is the first edition and it describes older Lua 5.0.